# How to write an rspec for do-end block and check method is called or not using stub/mock

Tags: ruby, rspec

All the unit test cases should be mocked/stubbed. Rspec for checkerror method and result method.

```
require 'yaml'
require_relative 'checkerror'

class Operations
  def initialize
      @path
      @checks_to_run
      @check
  end

  # This will prints the result of each file offences or no offences
  def result (result_log: File.new('result.txt', 'a+'))
    # @check.errors should be stubbed with a value to enter in if or else block
    if @check.errors.empty?
      # Output is printing in both console as well as file
      result_log.write("#{@check.checker.file_path} :: No offensenses detected\n")
      puts "#{@check.checker.file_path} :: No offensenses detected\n"
    else
      @check.errors.uniq.each do |err|
        puts "#{@check.checker.file_path} : #{err}\n"
        result_log.write("#{@check.checker.file_path} : #{err}\n")
      end
    end
    result_log.close
  end

  def rules_to_run
    @checks_to_run = YAML.load(File.read('lib/property.yaml'))
  end

  def path_of_directory
    @path = gets.chomp
  end

  def checkerror
    Dir[File.join(@path, '**/*.rb')].each do |file|
      @check = CheckError.new(file)
      @check.check_alphabetized_constants if @checks_to_run.include?('check_alphabetized_constants')
      @check.check_empty_line_before_return if @checks_to_run.include?('check_empty_line_before_return')
      #result is called to print errors
      result
    end
  end
end
```

I have written rspec for checkerror method

```
context '#checkerror' do
  it 'only check the method is called or not' do
    allow(@check_to_run).to receive(:include?).and_return(true)
    allow(@check).to receive(:check_alphabetized_contants)
    operation = Operation.new
    operation.checkerror
    expect(@check).to have_received(:check_alphabetized_constants)
  end
end
```

but getting error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into string.
```

I think haven't entered into loop of do-end block and stubbing is also syntacticly wrong I guess.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a full stack trace and any rspec initializers which would allow to reproduce your error.

Comment: This is quite a frustrating question, because you're asking for quite specific help to an rspec implementation, when the underlying code doesn't actually make sense. As I mentioned the previous occasion you posted this, you're not actually setting the `@path` or `@check_to_run` variables to anything, so this code isn't actually valid; what do you expect `Dir[File.join(nil, '**/*.rb')].each ....` to do?!

Comment: In other words, you can't do this: `operation = Operation.new`. Your `Operation` class is, at the very least, expecting to be initialised with a **`path`** and **`checks_to_run`**. I'll have a go at rewriting this for you in an answer, but you really need to take a step back and write a valid implementation before diving in to unit test it.

Comment: Sure. I will do

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly **minimal** change to your code, so that it makes a little bit more sense and can actually be tested:

```
require 'yaml'
require_relative 'checkerror'

class Operations
  def initialize(path: path_of_directory, checks_to_run: rules_to_run):                   
    @path = path      
    @checks_to_run = checks_to_run
  end                 
                      
  def log_result(file, errors, result_log: File.new('result.txt', 'a+'))
    if errors.empty?
      # Output is printing in both console as well as file
      result_log.write("#{file} :: No offensenses detected\n")
      puts "#{file} :: No offensenses detected\n"
    else                              
      errors.uniq.each do |err|
        puts "#{file} : #{err}\n"
        result_log.write("#{file} : #{err}\n")
      end                             
    end                               
    result_log.close                  
  end                                 
                                      
  def checkerror                      
    Dir[File.join(@path, '**/*.rb')].each do |file|
      checker = CheckError.new(file)
      checker.check_alphabetized_constants if @checks_to_run.include?('check_alphabetized_constants')
      checker.check_empty_line_before_return if @checks_to_run.include?('check_empty_line_before_return')
      log_result(file, checker.errors)
    end         
  end           
                
  # These methods feel very out-of-place!! It would be advisiable to move these outside of this class...
  def rules_to_run
    @checks_to_run = YAML.load(File.read('lib/property.yaml'))
  end           
                
  def path_of_directory
    @path = gets.chomp
  end           
end
```

Key notes:

- You need to actually **set the instance variables**. In your previous implementation, for example, `@path` was `nil` - so that didn't make any sense.
- Stubbing variables like `@checks_to_run` (which you mis-spelt, by the way!) isn't a great idea. Why not just set the variable to the desired value, in the first place?
- You can't stub variables that aren't even initialised, like `@check` -- that's not how stubbing works. Stubbing isn't like "spooky action at a distance", modifying how the code actually behaves; it's about setting response behaviour of dependencies.

So with that said... Here's roughly what your test could now look like:

```
describe '#checkerror' do
  let(:path) { Dir.mktmpdir('my-temporary-directory') }
  let!(:rb_file_in_path) { Tempfile.new('test-file.rb', tmpdir) }
  let(:mock_checker) { instance_double(CheckError) }

  it 'calls check_alphabetized_contants when this is a check to run' do
    allow(CheckError).to receive(:new).and_return(mock_checker)
    allow(mock_checker).to receive(:check_alphabetized_constants)

    operation = Operation.new(path: path, checks_to_run: ['check_alphabetized_constants'])
    operation.checkerror

    expect(mock_checker).to have_received(:check_alphabetized_constants)
  end
end
```